# Is this a Blocked design ANOVA, two way anova, or ANCOVA

Tags: anova, ancova, blocking

I am running ANOVA to test for a significant effect for some data, and a grad student said I should run an ANOVA test formatted like this in R to test for significance:

```
 x<- aov(angle~cond+sub)
```

where `cond=condition` with 4 levels (other, joint,self,diff), and `sub=subject`. My data being analyzed is formatted as follows:

```
sub   phase   cond     angle

1     1       diff     55.25
1     2       self     25.75
2     1       diff     38.65
2     2       other    55.75
3     1       diff     21.55
3     2       joint    65.65 
4     1       joint    55.00
4     2       other    51.51
```

and so on,
so each subject is only exposed to two of the four conditions. I get that the `aov()` formula he gave me is essentially trying to find the effect of condition on angle, while accounting for the variance caused by the effect of subject on angle. I am just a little confused then exactly what type of ANOVA I am running as I know the format of blocked ANOVA, two way ANOVA (without interactions), and ANCOVA all look generally like aov(Y~X + Z). Just looking for clarification.

Comment: It's not ancova, because for ancova one of the independent variables would have to be continuous.  To me, it 's a blocked model, because you're treating `subject` as a block.  But it doesn't matter what you call it. They're just names to help understanding.  You're using a *general linear model* approach, which is flexible enough to include all kinds of independent variables.  BTW, if you have many subjects, you might want to treat `subject` as a random effect rather than a fixed effect.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a two-way ANOVA without interaction to me:

- "condition" is a factor with 4 levels
- "subject" *seems* to be a factor with n levels.

Note that, depending on your exact protocol, a linear mixed model taking "subject" as a random effect may better represent the structure of your data. In which case look for `lme` or `lmer` functions of resp. `nlme` and `lme4`packages. But it's up to you, and the grad student. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode) for a discussion.

Sidenotes, if you stick to a non-mixed model (i.e. your current model). I'm by no means an expert in statistics nor R, but I'd like to add that:

- I've read somewhere that the `aov` function sometimes creates trouble, and that it's better to use `lm` instead. Can't provide a source, though.
- when getting the p-values from your ANOVA, consider the use of the `Anova` function from the `car` package rather than the standard `anova` function (from `base`). Why? Because the `Anova` function does not consider the first factor (here, "condition") to be more important than the second ("subject"). And that's generally what you want.